# Kinect for XBox One or Kinect for Xbox 360

Tags: video-game-console

I am looking for depth sensors to implement some aggorithms. I have heard Kinect is a good option. But, how does it work? Buy a Kinect and then connect to a computer? Which Kinect is recommended - Xbox 360 or Xbox one?

Can Kinect work without a XBox Console?

How is the data transferred to the PC ?

Answer (score 1):

Kinect for X-Box One is significantly higher-performing than the version for the 360 unit.   No matter what your version, there is an adapter cable available which converts the connection to USB and supplies power, and Windows already contains the Drivers for it.  There are various pieces of software which can use it, ranging from basic webcam software to the Kinect Studio and 3D Scan.

You should be aware that both versions of Kinect, and their adapter cables, have been discontinued by Microsoft; the adapter for the X-Box One version was discontinued in January 2018.   If you wish to obtain these without buying from the secondary market, I recommend moving quickly.

Comment: what is in this adaptor cable, if its just switching kinect port to usb, coz the adaptor costs 85 Euros ! So, one does not need a Xbox to get the Kinect working.. Then why is it called Kinect for X-Box ?

Comment: The adapter converts the X-Box connection to USB and also has a separate wall power supply, as normally the X-Box connection supplies more power than a USB connection.  The price used to be much lower, but since it's out of manufacture, rarity has increased the cost. 

Kinect is a part of the Microsoft ecosystem, and the OS used in these is basically just Windows with reskinning and DRM/playback firmware that allows the games to play.  It could have been released natively for PC as well, but Kinect was originally supposed to boost X-Box sales (and did, initially).

Comment: Will this work? I dont want the XBox. Just a connection between the PC and Kinect. Will this work, if I just want to do do some development on the PC? I dont want the Xbox...https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-AC-Adapter-Charger-Power-Supply-Cable-for-XBOX-360-XBOX360-Kinect-Sensor/153022897994?epid=1238590117&hash=item23a0e01f4a:g:1aUAAOSwwAda-qbq

Comment: That's the correct unit, yes.

Comment: actually, the adapter mentioned in the link wont work with Kinect V2 ( for Xbox One ), because its just for Kinect V1 ( for XBox 360 ). There is no alternative as of now other than to buy the expensive USB adapter or modify the Kinect V2.

Comment: Correct.  I'm not even sure if a generics market occurred for the XBOne version. The demand has never really been there for V2.